# Problems with seeds in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

My problem is the next one:

I have already done some seeds, and im trying to get the primary key to the another table/seed.

Here is the code i have problems:

```
$factory->define(App\Movimento::class,function(Faker\Generator $faker){

  $Transportador=App\Transportador::pluck('TransportadorId');

  $array =[

    'MovimentoId'   => $faker->randomNumber,

    'Data'          => $faker->date,

    'Destino'       => $faker->word,

    'EMExp'         => $faker->word,

    'Transp'        => $faker->randomNumber($Transportador)

  ];

  return $array;

});
```

So the "Transp" is a Foreign Key and i want the same key has the "TransportadorId" from the other seed.

Here is the code how is clear from errors:

```
  $factory->define(App\Transportador::class,function(Faker\Generator $faker){

  $nbDigits='3';

  $redDigits='9';

  $array =[

    'TransportadorId'    => $faker->randomNumber($nbDigits),

    'Nome'               => $faker->text,

    'Contribuinte'       => $faker->randomNumber($redDigits)

  ];

  return $array;

});
```

P.S-> I'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do:

```
$factory->define(App\Movimento::class,function(Faker\Generator $faker){

  $Transportadores = App\Transportador::all();

  $array =[

    'MovimentoId'   => $faker->randomNumber,

    'Data'          => $faker->date,

    'Destino'       => $faker->word,

    'EMExp'         => $faker->word,

    'Transp'        => $Transportadores->random()->TransportadorId

  ];

  return $array;

});
```